# Immutable (uncontainerized) elements in arrays created by deepmap

Tags: raku

If I understand the Raku docs correctly, the elements of Arrays are always containerized, i.e. Scalars. However, the deepmap method seems to create (inner) Arrays with uncontainerized elements:

```
my @a = [1, [2, 3]];
my @b = @a.deepmap: *.clone;
say @b[0].VAR.^name;     # Scalar, this is OK
say @b[1].^name;         # Array, as expected
say @b[1][0].VAR.^name;  # Int, why?
@b[0] = 4;               # this works
@b[1][0] = 5;            # error: Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

Why does this happen?

For context, I originally wanted to use `.deepmap: *.clone` to create a deep copy, but I needed the copy to be mutable. I solved the problem by using `@a.deepmap: { my $ = .clone }`, but I am still curious why this happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I understand the Raku docs correctly, the elements of Arrays are always containerized, i.e. Scalars.

That's *almost* correct, but not quite – Array initialization (i.e., with `[1, 2]`) containerizes the values, but that doesn't mean that elements are always containerized.  For example, you can [explicitly bind a value](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#Binding) to a position in an array.

Or, as you've discovered, you can wind up with a non-containerized value when creating an Array in an unusual way.  Let's take a look at what `deepmap` is doing here:

```raku
my @a = [1, [2, 3]];

@a.deepmap({.say; $_});  # OUTPUT: «1␤2␤3␤»
say @a.raku;             # OUTPUT: «[1 [2 3]]»
```

What's going on?  Well, `deepmap` is recursively descending into the structure and calling the function on each leaf element (that's why it prints `2` instead of `[2 3]` on the second iteration).  And then it *binds* the result to the slot it was iterating over.

So, with `.clone`, `deepmap` goes down to the leaf (e.g., `2`) and calls `.clone` on that value, gets `2` (an `Int`) and binds that to the position in the Array.

It appears that what you wanted to happen was for `.clone` to be called on `[2 3]`, rather than `2`.  If so, you could do that for lists with one level of nesting with (like above) with `.map(*.clone)`; for more complex nesting, you can use `duckmap` or tests inside a `map` expression (or, as you discovered, call `.clone` on the leaf values and add a `Scalar` manually.)

Comment: The docs say: “An Array is a List which forces all its elements to be scalar containers”. It seems the authors use the word “force” in a very unusual way… Also, the docs say that “binding Array slots directly to values is strongly discouraged”. It surprises me then that a standard method does something that is strongly discouraged.

Comment: What I still don't understand, though, is why the outermost array elements are not bound but assigned. Why is `@b[0]` a Scalar?

Comment: Hmm, yeah that "forces" language in the Array docs is a bit unfortunate and would be worth changing.  Re: "Why is @b[0] a Scalar" – it's because of the `@` sigil.  Note that `@a.deepmap(*.clone)[0].VAR.^name` returns `Int` (without a `Scalar`).  But when you assign the `deepmap`'s result into `@b`, the you get the default behavior of `@`: copy each element of the RHS and assign it to a Scalar bound to the corresponding position on the LHS.  (Note that you don't get a Scalar for `$b[0]` (or for `@b[0]` if you declare `@b` with `my @b is List =`).)

Comment: I feel this is actually worthy of making a Rakudo issue for

Comment: @NikolaBenes Just as "forced" is "unfortunate" wording, so too "strongly discouraged".